# Replace square brackets and comma in JSON file

Tags: python, json, dataframe, replace

I have a pandas dataframe `df` which is as follows:

```
| Name    | Age |
|---------|-----|
| Dinesh  | 23  |
| Karthik | 34  |
| Amit    |     |
| Mishra  | 10  |
```

I need to convert this into JSON so that my output is:

```
{
    "Name": "Dinesh",
    "Age": 23
}
{
    "Name": "Karthik",
    "Age": 34
}
{
    "Name": "Amit",
    "Age": null
}
{
    "Name": "Mishra",
    "Age": 10
}
```

I tried:

```
df.to_json('abcd', orient = 'records')
```

But I got the output for 'abcd' as:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "Dinesh",
        "Age": 23
    },
    {
        "Name": "Karthik",
        "Age": 34
    },
    {
        "Name": "Amit",
        "Age": null
    },
    {
        "Name": "Mishra",
        "Age": 10
    }
]
```

I want to eliminate square brackets and the comma after each curly bracket. How can I do this in Python?

Comment: Why do you want to? That would break the JSON file, it would contain multiple objects instead of a single root array.

Comment: I have an API that will consume the file only in a specific format. Hence I need to replace comma and square bracket

Answer (score 3):

Your desired output isn't a valid JSON format. You can manipulate the string representation of the JSON easily though.

```
import json

json.dumps(json_formatted).strip('[]').replace('},', '}')
```

`strip` removes all of the characters in the argument from the beginning and end of the string. The replace will just remove all of the commas following an end brace.

Comment: Is there a way to chain df.to_json('abcd', orient = 'records').strip('[]').replace('},', '}')

Comment: Ah, it looks like `to_json` dumps the string directly. (I don't use pandas.) Does that line exactly not work? What does it return?

Comment: it did not work. got error : "'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a full "working" example script?

Comment: I mean I want a full script that I can copy and paste to reproduce the crash. I don't know how to easily create a dataframe from scratch.

Comment: Ah, or I mean, don't run "that line exactly". Try `df.to_json(df, orient = 'records').strip('[]').replace('},', '}')` or whatever `to_json` command you used to get the output in your question.